# How to apply screen transitions in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have implemented the UIPageviewController in my code. But i don't know how to apply the transition  between the screens like in the below picture.

[image: Screen transition applied]

Right now my implementation looks like the below image.

[image: Without screen transistion]

Can you please advice how to apply the transition between the images ?

Is there any default api or delegate method to perform this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below sample project explains the screen transition between the views,

It's an easy way to integrate in the project.

https://github.com/icepat/ICETutorial

Answer (score 0):

You should init your pageviewcontroller with UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle=1 and UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal = 0

```
- (id)initWithTransitionStyle:(UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle)style navigationOrientation:(UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation)navigationOrientation options:(NSDictionary *)options
```